# Some NFT images minted from Candy Machine V2 are not displayed

Tags: solana, metaplex, pinata

I created [Candy Machine](https://solscan.io/account/Sj3A1yVzAu2YdVN9QXpr2bP2faRyPykLzaFWDyYYoo9) and I noticed that some NFT images are not displayed neither on wallet or solscan. Metadata and images were uploaded and pinned on Pinata using Candy Machine [upload](https://docs.metaplex.com/candy-machine-v2/creating-candy-machine) command which finished successfully.

Here is an example of [broken NFT](https://solscan.io/token/4ToXb3aD5YLpXqyZhcdp5ynpbXXFFjKjsaw1x94CTd7A).The metadata URI is pointed to: and image is pointing to. I looked at metadata several times and could not find what is the issue and why is this happening to some of the NFTs (here is the example of [valid NFT](https://solscan.io/token/BhAuRZ8f8y99kESHeQoFMi6PABYh7B3oydAuyWbHpQQs) that does  not have this problem).

Questions:

- What is the problem with metadata which is causing image not to be displayed?
- What is the best way to fix this? Metadata are mutable and I am planing to use metaboss to update URI of metadata file. Is this correct way of fixing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tony Boyle has a great point with updating your json.

Your problem gets visible when you run the json through a [JSON validator](https://jsononline.net/json-validator).
It will show that you have too many `}` in there. Therefore parsing the JSON fails in solscan, phantom etc.

What you have to do is

1. Modify the metadata to be a valid JSON file
2. upload it again
3. update the NFT uri e.g. with metaboss (if you need to update multiple NFTs) or  if its just one / a few https://sol-tools.tonyboyle.io/update-nft

Comment: I faced this issue several times with multiple candy machines, especially when working with pinata.

Comment: any source code for the tonyboyle website?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the URI metadata on solscan here

https://solscan.io/token/4ToXb3aD5YLpXqyZhcdp5ynpbXXFFjKjsaw1x94CTd7A#metadata

and swap to the URI version of the metadata for some reason it's returning an object keypair value out of every single character in the JSON for some reason, extremely weird. I'd highly recommended reuploading this JSON metadata file and then updating the metadata URI in the NFT to make the changes.

Metaboss is a great tool as you have researched that can do this for you.

1. Upload new Metadata json to ipfs or arweave.
2. Use Metaboss to udpate the NFT's metadata URI.

Hopefully this fixes your issue.

While not a conclusive answer as to "why" this happened, I don't really know the why. This is my first time in all the NFT's that I've seen that have behaved this way upon an upload and displaying the metadata.

If that doesn't fix your issue please stop by the Metaplex Discord server and chat with us there. :)

Edit: After further inspection it turns out your JSON file is of an invalid structure for this particular NFT so will definately need replacing.